# How to prevent warnings ocamlbuild/oasis warnings?

Tags: ocaml, ocamlbuild, oasis

I'm using OCaml, and Oasis to generate the appropriate input to ocamlbuild.

Very straightforward question here - every time I go to compile my software  with `ocaml setup.ml -build` I get these warnings:

```
W: Cannot get variable ext_obj
W: Cannot get variable ext_lib
W: Cannot get variable ext_dll
W: Cannot get variable ocamlfind
```

How do I get these to stop?

**Edit**

I found all of these were defined in the myocamlbuild.ml generated by oasis. Likely the shell that I work with, zsh, is different than from how the ocaml source is pulling it's informations on such things as ocamlfind location and the other variables. Hence the warnings. I'll see if I can't figure out how to fix the warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me:

```
ocaml setup.ml -quiet -build
```

But it is better to fix this warnings.

Comment: Oh man, what are the odds Ivan would answer this. I literally got this popup on my phone, saw it was you and busted out laughing